# Checking if pull request have had changes requested with Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I've been reading the Github API for a while now and I'm unable to find if there's an event list or a history of some sort to see if changes has been requested to a pull request and by whom.

I'm trying to make a script to analyse the efficiency of our code review staff.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, yay:

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/

> Pull Request Reviews are groups of Pull Request Review Comments on the Pull Request, grouped together with a state and optional body comment.